# Detect Shift + Enter on iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Is it possible to detect a Shift + Enter key combination on iOS in a `UITextView`?

Comment: What do you want to do differently? Use `... shouldChangeTextInRange...` delegate method and see if there is any difference between Enter and Shift+Enter.

Comment: But how would do detect if the shift key is pressed or active when return is pressed?

Comment: As I said, implement that `UITextViewDelegate` delegate method and look at the value to see if there is any difference. Probably not. And again, what is your goal? There may be another way.

Comment: There isn't.  :)  I want to do separate actions if it's a return or shift + return.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to do something different. What is it? No one can offer help if you keep it a secret. :)

Answer (score 7):

Using Swift you can intercept the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a `UIResponder` subclass using something like this:

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    get {
        return [UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: .shift , action: #selector(handleShiftEnter(command:)))]
    }
}

func handleShiftEnter(command: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Combo pressed! Default action intercepted!")
}
```

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot! Thank you! I have implemented the custom textview in gist: https://gist.github.com/yosshi4486/ff37ffee79886fd2beabde375f65ba9a.

Comment: Did this work with the iOS keyboard? In my tests, it only works with a bluetooth-connected physical keyboard.

Comment: FWIW, I'm trying to allow for soft newlines by tapping return while holding down the Shift key on the _iOS virtual keyboard_ ([similar to this](https://wccftech.com/how-to/quick-tip-how-to-add-line-breaks-using-ios-ipados-keyboard/)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subclass of `UITextView` that detects enter key and shift enter key combination on an external physical keyboard.

```
protocol TextViewWithKeyDetectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func enterKeyWasPressed(textView: UITextView)
    func shiftEnterKeyPressed(textView: UITextView)
}

class TextViewWithKeyDetection: UITextView {
    weak var keyDelegate: TextViewWithKeyDetectionDelegate?
    
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        [UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: .shift, action: #selector(shiftEnterKeyPressed)),
         UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(enterKeyPressed))]
    }
    
    @objc func shiftEnterKeyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        keyDelegate?.shiftEnterKeyPressed(textView: self)
    }
    
    @objc func enterKeyPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        keyDelegate?.enterKeyWasPressed(textView: self)
    }
}
```